# Server Side Timer using PHP for web application

Tags: php, timer

I am developing a quiz page showing one question at a time. I want to create a timer of 15 minutes using PHP with the following functionality:

- a) The timer should update every one minute and should be bound with
  a div.
- b) When the timer expires a certain code should execute.
- c)
  The page should not be updated only the dive containing the timer
  should be updated.
- d) The page should not be freezed i.e. sleep
  function should not be used.

Comment: What code have you done yet ? Can you provide the steps you have tried yet ? So that We can help you in better way.

Comment: Code:
<?php
$timer=60*15;
$timestamp_file='end_timestamp.txt';
if(!file_exists($timestamp_file))
{
file_put_contents($timestamp_file,time()+$timer);
}
$end_timestamp=file_get_contents($timestamp_file);
$current_timestamp=time();
$difference=$end_timestamp-$current_timestamp;
if($difference<0)
{
}
?>

Comment: @AarthnaMaheshwari please edit this in your original post.